# Spring Rest docs attributes

Tags: spring-restdocs

I a trying to use the attributes method as described [here,](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-customizing-including-extra-information)
but it is not recognized. Nor is the method key recognized.

Am I missing a static import?

My code:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post(URL_PREFIX + "/scripts/")
     .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     .content(asJsonString(script)))
     .andExpect(status().is(HttpStatus.CREATED.value()))
     .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON))
     .andDo(document("create-script-example"
     , links(
        linkWithRel("self").description("Link self"),
        linkWithRel("script").description("Link to the created script resource")),
     responseFields(
        attributes(
           key("title").value("Fields for user creation")),
        fieldWithPath("_links").description("The available links"),
        fieldWithPath("name").description("the name of the created script"),
        fieldWithPath("domain").description("the domain of created the script").optional(),
        fieldWithPath("script").description("the code in Groovy format of the created script"))
     , requestFields(
       fieldWithPath("id").description("the id of the script to create, should be null"),
       fieldWithPath("name").description("the name of the script to create"),
       fieldWithPath("domain").description("the domain of the script to create"),
       fieldWithPath("script").description("the code in Groovy format of the script to create")
)))
.andReturn();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer :
import static org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.Attributes.attributes;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.Attributes.key;